# Asp.net Link onRowCommand not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

my GridView id given below, (Asp.net web from application)

```
asp:GridView ID="grid"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="913px" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
          ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" ShowHeader="true" onrowcommand="ContactsGridView_RowCommand" >
```

my method for onRowCommand

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using FirstWebForm.business_objects;

namespace FirstWebForm
{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                grid.DataSource = dataaccess.Instance.getAll();
                grid.DataBind();
            }
        }

        void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

But it hits a error
[image]

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.about_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ContactsGridView_RowCommand' and no extension method 'ContactsGridView_RowCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.about_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ContactsGridView_RowCommand` method to be `public` or `protected` if it is to be ran in the code behind:

```
protected void ContactsGridView_RowCommand
```

Or put the method on the page in a script tag and it will work as is

```
<script runat="server">

  void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
   ...
  }
</script>
```